# if you downloaded a high API level does that mean that you don't need to download older aipies?

Tags: android-studio

I recently downloaded a package . It was API 25.I only download that. And would doing so allow the compatibility  work for older versions?

Comment: No. Newer versions have functionality that older ones don't, and to make sure you're not using something that doesn't exist (or has changed), you need to actually build against that earlier version.

Comment: So if i download the most common used  Apis then it would be on the market for more people?